# frontier_exploration with turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, frontier-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the frontier_exploration package to work with my TurtleBot. But so far it's not working.

The launch file

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <remap from="scan" to="/scan2" />
    <rosparam>
      occ_thresh: 0.25
      odom_frame: odom
      map_update_interval: 5.0
      maxUrange: 6.0
      maxRange: 8.0
      sigma: 0.05
      kernelSize: 1
      lstep: 0.05
      astep: 0.05
      iterations: 5
      lsigma: 0.075
      ogain: 1.0
      lskip: 0
      srr: 0.01
      srt: 0.02
      str: 0.01
      stt: 0.02
      linearUpdate: 0.5
      angularUpdate: 0.436
      temporalUpdate: -1.0
      resampleThreshold: 0.5
      particles: 80
      xmin: -1.0
      ymin: -1.0
      xmax: 1.0
      ymax: 1.0
      delta: 0.05
      llsamplerange: 0.01
      llsamplestep: 0.01
      lasamplerange: 0.005
      lasamplestep: 0.005
      base_frame: base_link
    </rosparam>
  </node>
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz">
  </node>

          <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/velocity_smoother.launch.xml"/>
          <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/safety_controller.launch.xml"/>

          <arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />

   <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
          <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
          <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
          <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
          <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
          <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
          <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
          <remap from="cmd_vel" to="navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel"/>
          <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   update_frequency: 3.0
   publish_frequency: 0.0
   static_map: true
   transform_tolerance: 0.5
```

local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:
   global_frame: /odom
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   update_frequency: 5.0
   publish_frequency: 2.0
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
   width: 4.0
   height: 4.0
   resolution: 0.05
   transform_tolerance: 0.5
```

Errors from the frontier_exploration terminal

```
[ WARN] [1414574875.215553173]: Please select an initial point for exploration inside the polygon
[ INFO] [1414574876.981956729]: Sending goal
[ INFO] [1414574877.352866124]: Using plugin "static"
[ INFO] [1414574877.621707478]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1414574877.775594588]: Resizing costmap to 576 X 288 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1414574877.847249155]: Received a 576 X 288 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1414574877.847298258]: Subscribing to updates
[ INFO] [1414574878.016550480]: Using plugin "explore_boundary"
[ INFO] [1414574878.541237670]: Using plugin "sensor"
[ INFO] [1414574878.664303536]:     Subscribed to Topics: /scan2
[ INFO] [1414574879.327905514]: Using plugin "inflation"
[ERROR] [1414574880.852823897]: Exception thrown while processing service call: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1414574873.590463123 but the earliest data is at time 1414574878.157772422, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]
[ERROR] [1414574880.853237138]: Service call failed: service [/explore_server/explore_costmap/explore_boundary/update_boundary_polygon] responded with an error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1414574873.590463123 but the earliest data is at time 1414574878.157772422, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]
[ERROR] [1414574880.853397382]: Failed to set region boundary
```

Errors from my gmapping launch file terminal

```
[ WARN] [1414574406.526808975]: Could not transform the global plan to the frame of the controller
[ WARN] [1414574406.726686480]: Rotate recovery behavior started.
[ERROR] [1414574407.526747008]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1414574410.178328037 but the latest data is at time 1414574407.557751617, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]

[ERROR] [1414574407.526792212]: Global Frame: odom Plan Frame size 83: map

[ WARN] [1414574407.526823145]: Could not transform the global plan to the frame of the controller
[ERROR] [1414574407.726658949]: Aborting because a valid control could not be found. Even after executing all recovery behaviors
```

This is from roswtf

```
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
ERROR: connection refused to [http://192.168.1.101:57184/]
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 4 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /rviz:
   * /tf_static
   * /exploration_polygon_marker_array
   * /map_updates
 * /slam_gmapping:
   * /tf_static
 * /explore_server:
   * /explore_server/explore_costmap/footprint
   * /explore_server/cancel
   * /tf_static
   * /map_updates
   * /explore_server/goal
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager:
   * /tf_static
 * /mobile_base_nodelet_manager:
   * /kobuki_safety_controller/reset
   * /kobuki_safety_controller/disable
   * /mobile_base/events/bumper
   * /kobuki_safety_controller/enable
   * /mobile_base/events/cliff
   * /mobile_base/events/wheel_drop
   * /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
 * /move_base:
   * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint
   * /scan
   * /scan1
   * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint
   * /tf_static
   * /mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud
   * /scan3
 * /robot_pose_ekf:
   * /tf_static
 * /rviz_1414572817549013793:
   * /tf_static

WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:
 * /turtlebot_node->/rqt_gui_py_node_5547 (/turtlebot_node/parameter_updates)
 * /turtlebot_node->/rqt_gui_py_node_5547 (/turtlebot_node/parameter_descriptions)

WARNING These nodes have died:
 * turtlebot_laptop_battery-8
 * kinect_breaker_enabler-4

WARNING Received out-of-date/future transforms:
 * receiving transform from [/robot_state_publisher] that differed from ROS time by 3.751655102s
 * receiving transform from [/camera_base_link1] that differed from ROS time by 2.878755525s
 * receiving transform from [/camera_base_link3] that differed from ROS time by 2.878594282s
 * receiving transform from [/camera_base_link2] that differed from ROS time by 2.87764309s
 * receiving transform from [/camera_base_link] that differed from ROS time by 2.879013752s
 * receiving transform from [/robot_pose_ekf] that differed from ROS time by 2.751272917s
 * receiving transform from [/ira_static_broadcaster2] that differed from ROS time by 3.765229121s


Found 3 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /rviz_1414572817549013793

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan->/explore_server (/scan2)
 * /camera_base_link2->/rviz_1414572817549013793 (/tf)
 * /camera_base_link->/rviz_1414572817549013793 (/tf)
 * /slam_gmapping->/rviz_1414572817549013793 (/tf)
 * /ira_static_broadcaster2->/rviz_1414572817549013793 (/tf)
 * /robot_pose_ekf->/rviz_1414572817549013793 (/tf)
 * /camera_base_link3->/rviz_1414572817549013793 (/tf)
 * /robot_state_publisher->/rviz_1414572817549013793 (/tf)
 * /camera_base_link1->/rviz_1414572817549013793 (/tf)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/rviz_1414572817549013793/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rviz_1414572817549013793/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://192.168.1.101:36179]
 * service [/rviz_1414572817549013793/reload_shaders] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rviz_1414572817549013793/reload_shaders], address [rosrpc://192.168.1.101:36179]
 * service [/rviz_1414572817549013793/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rviz_1414572817549013793/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://192.168.1.101:36179]
```

I believe that the tf tree is fine. But i'll attached it anyways along with rqt_graph, the launch file and costmaps config.

EDIT: Uni's network is blocking imgur and other important stuffs. I'll figure how to upload things. Brb.

EDIT: tf tree

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196189/frontier_exploration-with-turtlebot/) by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-05**:
have you finally got it to work? its driving me nuts lol any luck, progress, idea? here is my [Question](http://answers.ros.org/question/208607/frontier-exploration-dont-publish-any-goals-to-explore/) I'd appreciate any little help. thanks

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2015-05-06**:
i really can't pin down the exact problem. sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. even with the clock synced properly and i also set the openni publish transform to false to fix the kinect's tf issues. we've moved on from mapping to olfaction recently so I can't help you much for the time being.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-06**:
thank you for the response. one last thing, i thought i would borrow the configs that you posted here, to test on my bot. apart from clock n stuff, you did use the same config as posted here right?

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2015-05-06**:
Almost all of it are the same.
I've increased the transform tolerance, update_frequency, publish_frequency and changed robot_base_frame to base_link on the global costmap params and frontier's launch file.
I think they must be the same. Check your launch file....

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2015-05-06**:
...the one i've uploaded was mainly about gmapping & move_base. i think i should update my Q.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-06**:
Thanks a bunch for the replies. im so stuck on finding a working exploration package you have no idea lol. have a good day!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-06-15**:
Maybe either of you can help me at http://answers.ros.org/question/237001/turtlebotfrontier_exploration-robot-never-moves-while-sending-goal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to the time difference in the timestamps (3-5 seconds), it looks like you have tf setup problems, or some serious latency issues.

You can set a tolerance value on `amcl` to future date the tf timestamps and prevent extrapolation errors, but the most you'd ever need would be ~0.1 s or so.

Are you running the nodes on separate computers? Are the clocks synced with chrony or something similar?

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-10-30**:
I am using two computers. One laptop on the bot and a pc as workstation. Ran all the essentials like turtlebot startup and kinect's packages on the laptop. All other nodes are on the pc.

I do get some tf error sometimes. All of it were kinect's tf. It flickers on RViz.

Updated the Q with tf frames

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-30**:
Try going through [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Timing_issues.2C_TF_complaining_about_extrapolation_into_the_future.3F)

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-11-27**:
[ WARN] [1417145721.905257930]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1417145721.9052, global_pose stamp: 1417145721.3650, tolerance: 0.5000
[ WARN] [1417145722.105144612]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-11-28**:
That is also a TF issue, likely cause by your multi-machine setup. Please open a separate question if you need more info about setting up your network properly. Main issues would be latency, and time synchronization.

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-10**:
Hi, I am having the exact same problem as described in this post but I'm not running on multiple workstations. I am running everything on one computer and i'm running the nodes separately by their own launch file (i.e. gmapping, move_base, TF from odom->base_link->laser, and exploration).

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-10**:
Also, I'm using gmapping to provide the map->odom transform and of course to build the map.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-03-10**:
I doubt it's the exact same problem, since @charkoteow's issue was extremely post-dated timestamps. Either way, please open a new question, and provide some more information.